# Google Chart bars half the correct height in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: google-visualization, ubuntu-16.04, wkhtmltopdf

My Google Chart works perfectly in the browser:

[Works perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5G60.png)

However, when I try to render this as a PDF using:

`wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 2000 --print-media-type chart_dummy.html chart_dummy.pdf`

the heights of the bars get halved, and the colour code goes missing:

[Rendered PDF with bars half height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uG8N.png)

I take it there must be some wkhtmltopdf option to correct this, but I can't for the life of me identify one.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus), and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt).

My visualization function is

```
       function drawVisualization() {// Create the data table.

       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

       data.addColumn('string', 'focus name');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Exceeded');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Achieved');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Not Achieved');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Regressed');

       var width = $($('.container-fluid')[0]).width();
       var height = $($('.container-fluid')[0]).height();

       var options = {
          'width': width,
          'height': height,
          'chartArea': {top:10},
          title: String(),
          vAxis: {
               title: '% Progress',
               minValue: 0,
               maxValue: 100,
               format: '#\'%\'',
               baseline: 0,
          },
          hAxis: {
               title: ''
          },
          seriesType: 'bars',
          series: {
              5: {
                  type: 'line'
              }
          },
          colors: ['#ffe400', '#03ea74', '#ffa000', '#0095ff'],
          annotations: {
              alwaysOutside: true,
              textStyle: {
                 fontSize: 20,
                 auraColor: '#eee',
                 color: '#eee'
              }
          },
          animation: {
             duration: 2000,
             easing: 'linear',
             startup: true
          },
          legend: 'bottom'
       };

       reportData = {
          "combined": {
              "exceeded": "34",
              "achieved": "72",
              "not_achieved": "14",
              "regressed": "8"
          }
       };

       data.addRows([
           ['All Focus Areas', Number(reportData['combined']['exceeded']), Number(reportData['combined']['achieved']), Number(reportData['combined']['not_achieved']), Number(reportData['combined']['regressed'])]
       ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

Has anyone a clue how to make the PDF the same as the Browser rendering?